# Laravel calculate amounts in resource with nested relationships

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, nested, relationship

I have this structure:

`invoices`, `invoices_lines`, `invoices_lines_taxes`, `taxes`

Relationships:

`invoices` is one-to-many with `invoices_lines`.

`invoices_lines` is many-to-many with `taxes` with intermediate table `invoices_lines_taxes`

Models:

`Invoice`

```
public function lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InvoiceLine::class, 'invoice', 'id');
}
```

`InvoiceLine`

```
public function taxes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tax::class, 'invoices_lines_taxes', 'line', 'tax');
}
```

Resources:

`InvoiceResource`

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'invoice_date' => $this->invoice_date,
        'reference' => $this->reference,
        'number' => $this->number,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'state' => $this->state,
        'type' => $this->type,
        'lines' => InvoiceLineResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('lines')),
        'amount' => $this->whenLoaded('lines', function () {
            return $this->lines()->sum(DB::raw('unit_price * quantity'));
        }),
    ];
}
```

I have managed to calculate the amounts on the InvoiceResource.
But I need to calculate these amounts with taxes.

How can I do it?

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'invoice_date' => $this->invoice_date,
        'reference' => $this->reference,
        'number' => $this->number,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'state' => $this->state,
        'type' => $this->type,
        'lines' => InvoiceLineResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('lines')),
        'amount' => $this->whenLoaded('lines', function () {
            return $this->lines()->sum(DB::raw('unit_price * quantity'));
        }),
        'amount_taxes' => ?????
    ];
}
```

I can get the tax doing these queries by SQL... but how can I translate it to Laravel eloquent way?

```
select id from invoices -- get invoice_id.
select id from invoices_lines where invoice = $invoice_id -- get id of invoice_lines
select tax from invoices_lines_taxes where line = $invoice_line_id -- get the id of tax.
select rate from taxes where id = $tax_id
```

and rate is the float (percentage) which I have to multiplicate with the amount.
So the expression should be: `invoices_lines.unit_price` * `invoices_lines.quantity` * `taxes.rate`

Comment: About tthe 4 queries you run at the end: Shouldn't there be a `limit 1` or are all those `where` statements supposed to be  `where in`?

Comment: Yes the queries are only for explanation. An invoice has one or more invoice_lines. Then each invoice_line (by business logic) only have one tax.